# Zoom the canvas with respect to mouse cordinates

Tags: javascript, html, css, canvas, html5-canvas

I have a very simple application, on which I draw the image on canvas perfectly. I am translating the context by image.width/2, image.height/2 and set the destination point as -image.width/2, -image.height/2.

```
        function draw() {
        window.canvas = document.getElementById('canvas');
        window.ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
        window.image = document.createElement("img");
        image.onload = function() {
            canvas.width = image.width;
            canvas.height = image.height;
            ctx.clearRect(0,0,canvas.width,canvas.height);
            ctx.translate(image.width/2,image.height/2);
            ctx.drawImage(image,-image.width/2,-image.height/2);
        };
        image.src = 'rec.JPG';
    }
```

This is displaying the image as it supposed to be. So considering this conept that if I want to make the center point of image in center of canvas I should do this as I did above. Now, I want user to click on canvas, I am getting mouse coordinates. Then I want to scale this image and redraw the canvas such that user will see that part of the image in center (zoomed version). The code is as follow:

```
        function zoom(evt) {
        var x = getMousePos(canvas, evt).x;
        var y = getMousePos(canvas, evt).y;
        canvas.width = image.width;
        canvas.height = image.height;
        ctx.clearRect(0,0,canvas.width,canvas.height);
        ctx.translate(x,y);
        ctx.scale(1.5, 1.5);
        ctx.drawImage(image,-x,-y);
    }

    function getMousePos(canvas, evt) {
        var rect = canvas.getBoundingClientRect();
        return {
            x: evt.clientX - rect.left,
            y: evt.clientY - rect.top
        };
    }
```

But I am not getting the right results somehow. I want to see the region where user clicked and then I again want to click to zoom out and thats it. I can do a later part easily but having problem with zooming the perfect region. I saw similiar questions on stackoverflow, but they aren't meeting my requirement. This is my html and css:

```
    <style>
    .container {
        height: 500px;
    }
    .container .image-container {
        height: 500px;
        width: 50%;
        overflow: auto;
        position: absolute;
        border: 1px solid;
    }

    img {
        display: none;
    }

    canvas {
        width: 100%;
    }
</style>
<body onload="draw()">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="image-container">
    <canvas
            id="canvas"
            onclick="zoom(event)"
    >
    </canvas>
   </div>
   </div>
</body>
```

P.S: I don't want panning. Just zoom-in and out on clicks. You can play with the snippet.

```js
        function draw() {
            window.canvas = document.getElementById('canvas');
            window.ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
            window.image = document.createElement("img");
            window.isZoom = false;
            image.onload = function() {
                canvas.width = image.width;
                canvas.height = image.height;
                ctx.clearRect(0,0,canvas.width,canvas.height);
                ctx.translate(image.width/2,image.height/2);
                ctx.drawImage(image,-image.width/2,-image.height/2);
            };
            image.src = 'https://d85ecz8votkqa.cloudfront.net/support/help_center/Print_Payment_Receipt.JPG';
        }

        function zoom(evt) {
            if(!isZoom) {
                var x = getMousePos(canvas, evt).x;
                var y = getMousePos(canvas, evt).y;
                canvas.width = image.width;
                canvas.height = image.height;
                ctx.clearRect(0,0,canvas.width,canvas.height);
                ctx.translate(x,y);
                ctx.scale(2, 2);
                ctx.drawImage(image,-x,-y);
                canvas.style.cursor = 'zoom-out';
                isZoom = true;
            } else {
                canvas.width = image.width;
                canvas.height = image.height;
                ctx.clearRect(0,0,canvas.width,canvas.height);
                ctx.translate(image.width/2,image.height/2);
                ctx.drawImage(image,-image.width/2,-image.height/2);
                isZoom=false;
                canvas.style.cursor = 'zoom-in';
            }
        }

        function getMousePos(canvas, evt) {
            var rect = canvas.getBoundingClientRect();
            return {
                x: evt.clientX - rect.left,
                y: evt.clientY - rect.top
            };
        }
```

```css
    <style>
        .container {
            height: 500px;
        }
        .container .image-container {
            height: 500px;
            width: 50%;
            overflow: auto;
            position: absolute;
            border: 1px solid;
        }

        img {
            display: none;
        }

        canvas {
            width: 100%;
            cursor: zoom-in;
        }
    </style>
```

```html
<body onload="draw()">
<div class="container">
    <div class="image-container">
        <canvas
                id="canvas"
                onclick="zoom(event)"
        >
        </canvas>
    </div>
</div>
</body>
```

Comment: Just noticed that your code produces an identical output, regardless of where the picture is clicked. Without looking at the code, I suspect that If you translate by -mouseX,-mouseY, the clicked-point is now at the origin, (0,0). If you then scale this before translating back again by +mouseX,+mouseY, you'll find something fun staring back at you. :)

Answer (score 2):

You where really close, just have to mix the scale into your drawing of the image

```js
function draw() {
  window.canvas = document.getElementById('canvas');
  window.ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
  window.image = document.createElement("img");
  window.isZoom = false;
  image.onload = function() {
    canvas.width = image.width;
    canvas.height = image.height;
    ctx.drawImage(image, 0,0);
  };
  image.src = 'https://d85ecz8votkqa.cloudfront.net/support/help_center/Print_Payment_Receipt.JPG';
}

function zoom(evt) {
  canvas.width = image.width;
  canvas.height = image.height;
  ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
  var scale = 2
  if (!isZoom) {
    var pos = getMousePos(canvas, evt);    
    ctx.scale(scale, scale);
    ctx.drawImage(image, -pos.x*scale*scale, -pos.y*scale*scale);
    canvas.style.cursor = 'zoom-out';
  } else {
    ctx.drawImage(image, 0, 0);
    canvas.style.cursor = 'zoom-in';
  }
  isZoom = !isZoom
}

function getMousePos(canvas, evt) {
  var rect = canvas.getBoundingClientRect();
  return {
    x: evt.clientX - rect.left,
    y: evt.clientY - rect.top
  };
}
```

```css
.container {
  height: 500px;
}

.container .image-container {
  height: 500px;
  width: 50%;
  overflow: auto;
  position: absolute;
  border: 1px solid;
}

img {
  display: none;
}

canvas {
  width: 100%;
  cursor: zoom-in;
}
```

```html
<body onload="draw()">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="image-container">
      <canvas id="canvas" onclick="zoom(event)">
        </canvas>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
```

Besides the addition of `var scale` I did some cleanup to your code:

```
var x = getMousePos(canvas, evt).x;
var y = getMousePos(canvas, evt).y;
```

That was kind of a wasteful double call to getMousePos

Comment: This solution is not working well when you rotate the image. let it rotate by let say 180, and then zoom in, its not giving correct results then.

Comment: Yes it might not work well when the image is rotated, and I'm sure there are many more cases that you did not mentioned on your question that it will not work well, you have to code and test those cases.

Comment: I update the question, you can check the rotation case now.